# Uniform convergence and continuity from PMA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

After reading theorem 7.12 I have one question.

We must prove that $f$ is continuous at $E$. We take $x\in E$ which is also a limit point of $E$ and apply previous theorem 7.11 and we get that $f$ is continuous at $E\cap E'$ where $E'$ the set of all limit points of $E$. We have shown that $f$ is continuous at every point of $E\cap E'$.

But $f$ is continuous at any isolated points of $E$ where $E=\text{Dom}(f)$. Hence $f$ is continuous at whole $E$.

I would be grateful to anyone who says is my reasoning true?

Comment: If $x$ is an isolated point of $E$ then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $y\notin\operatorname{Dom}(f)$, so it is vacuously true that a function is continuous at an isolated point.

Comment: @Math1000, Since $x$ is an isolated point of $E$ then $\exists \delta>0$ such that $N'_{\delta}(x)\cup E=\varnothing $ or $N_{\delta}(x)\cup E=\{x\}$. Then for any $\varepsilon >0$ we can pick above $\delta>0$ such that the only point $t\in E$ with $|t-x|<\delta$ is $t=x$ then $|f(x)-f(x)|=0<\varepsilon.$ Right?

Comment: @Math1000, So my above reasonings at above post are right?

Comment: Yes, essentially the book is saying that 7.12 follows from 7.11, so there isn't really anything further to prove.

Comment: @Math1000, Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can prove 7.12 , without difficulty,in a general way without regard to isolated or accumulation points. But your reasoning is true.